# I tried to use groupBy on my dataframe after adding a new column but I faced the problem Task NotSerializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my code, I am getting the `Task Not Serializable` Error when I do this `result.groupBy("value")`

```
object Test extends  App {

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[4]")
    .appName("https://SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  def myUDF = udf { (v: Double) =>
    if (v < 0) 100
    else 500
  }

  val central: DataFrame = Seq((1, 2014),(2, 2018)).toDF("key", "year1")

  val other1: DataFrame = Seq((1, 2016),(2, 2015)).toDF("key", "year2")

  val result = central.join(other1, Seq("key"))
    .withColumn("value", myUDF(col("year2")))
  result.show()

  val result2 = result.groupBy("value")
  .count()
 result2.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same  code I havent got any Task Not Serializable. Some where you have misconception.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object Test extends  App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[4]")
    .appName("https://SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  def myUDF = udf { (v: Double) =>
    if (v < 0) 100
    else 500
  }

  val central: DataFrame = Seq((1, 2014),(2, 2018)).toDF("key", "year1")

  val other1: DataFrame = Seq((1, 2016),(2, 2015)).toDF("key", "year2")

  val result = central.join(other1, Seq("key"))
    .withColumn("value", myUDF(col("year2")))
  result.show()

  val result2 = result.groupBy("value")
    .count()
  result2.show()
}
```

Result :

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|key|year1|year2|value|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1| 2014| 2016|  500|
|  2| 2018| 2015|  500|
+---+-----+-----+-----+

+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|  500|    2|
+-----+-----+
```

#### Conclusion :

This kind of situations will arise when your spark version not compatible with your Scala version.

check this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core for all versions and corresonding scala versions you need to use.

[image]

Comment: Actually the problem was resolved when I added a cache() just after withColumn(): like this : "  val result = central.join(other1, Seq("key"))
    .withColumn("value", myUDF(col("year2"))).cache()
  result.show()" and now It works, Do you have any explanation for that, because I don't really understand, Is it a memory management problem ? Thank you

Comment: I totally accept your answer and with pleasure for sure, I want to know more about Spark since I am new in this field. Just if you can explain more what do you mean by misconception ?

Comment: I just tried to run this same code but this time with scala version 2.11 and It worked, Any ideas ? (I was runnig the code with scala 2.12 the first time)

Comment: Perfect  that's the cause. Scala is not backward compatible. New version  with your spark is not compatible